# Add Swift Package in Release mode

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, swift-package

I want to add a Swift Package in Release mode to my current XCode project. But I can't find a way to do this.

**Background**

Adding a package dependency from GitHub into a XCode project seems to add the code itself. When starting the app in debug mode, then the package is also loaded in debug mode (presumably to be able to debug this package as well). But the package in question is really slow in debug mode which makes it cumbersome to debug the app.

**Actual Question**

Is there a way to include a Swift Package in Release mode from GitHub into a XCode project?

**Note**

I know that it is supposed to work using other package managers like Carthage for example. I could also go ahead and build the library locally and include this in my project. But I'm looking for a build-in XCode of doing this without any effort on the outside.

Comment: If you don’t use the package in debug mode it shouldn’t be much of a factor, you just have to use dependency injection to replace what the package does.